# How to return promise to the router callback in NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, bluebird

I am new to nodejs/expressjs and mongodb. I am trying to create an API that exposes data to my mobile app that I am trying to build using Ionic framework.

I have a route setup like this

```
router.get('/api/jobs', (req, res) => {
  JobModel.getAllJobsAsync().then((jobs) => res.json(jobs)); //IS THIS THe CORRECT WAY?
});
```

I have a function in my model that reads data from Mongodb. I am using the Bluebird promise library to convert my model functions to return promises.

```
const JobModel = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/Job'));
```

My function in the model

```
static getAllJobs(cb) {

    MongoClient.connectAsync(utils.getConnectionString()).then((db) => {

      const jobs = db.collection('jobs');
      jobs.find().toArray((err, jobs) => {

        if(err) {
          return cb(err);
        }

        return cb(null, jobs);
      });
    });
  }
```

The promisifyAll(myModule) converts this function to return a promise.

What I am not sure is,

- If this is the correct approach for returning data to the route callback function from my model?
- Is this efficient?
- Using promisifyAll is slow? Since it loops through all functions in the module and creates a copy of the function with Async as suffix that now returns a promise. When does it actually run? This is a more generic question related to node require statements. See next point.
- When do all require statements run? When I start the nodejs server? Or when I make a call to the api?

Comment: Take a look at mongoose module.

Comment: @Yahya I had researched about it. But I don't want to enforce schemas on my documents.

Comment: What about [Monk](https://automattic.github.io/monk/) ?

Comment: @Yahya - I did try using mongojs. But these libraries don't really provide the latest available features/functions as native mongod so I am trying to use the native mongod.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic structure is more-or-less correct, although your use of `Promise.promisifyAll` seems awkward to me. The basic issue for me (and it's not really a problem - your code looks like it will work) is that you're mixing and matching promise-based and callback-based asynchronous code. Which, as I said, should still work, but I would prefer to stick to one as much as possible.

If your model class is **your** code (and not some library written by someone else), you could easily rewrite it to use promises directly, instead of writing it for callbacks and then using `Promise.promisifyAll` to wrap it.

Here's how I would approach the `getAllJobs` method:

```
static getAllJobs() {

    // connect to the Mongo server
    return MongoClient.connectAsync(utils.getConnectionString())

        // ...then do something with the collection
        .then((db) => {
            // get the collection of jobs
            const jobs = db.collection('jobs');

            // I'm not that familiar with Mongo - I'm going to assume that
            // the call to `jobs.find().toArray()` is asynchronous and only 
            // available in the "callback flavored" form.

            // returning a new Promise here (in the `then` block) allows you
            // to add the results of the asynchronous call to the chain of
            // `then` handlers. The promise will be resolved (or rejected) 
            // when the results of the `job().find().toArray()` method are 
            // known
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                jobs.find().toArray((err, jobs) => {
                    if(err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(jobs);
                });
            });
        });
}
```

This version of `getAllJobs` returns a promise which you can chain `then` and `catch` handlers to. For example:

```
JobModel.getAllJobs()

    .then((jobs) => {
        // this is the object passed into the `resolve` call in the callback
        // above. Do something interesting with it, like
        res.json(jobs);
    })

    .catch((err) => {
        // this is the error passed into the call to `reject` above
    });
```

Admittedly, this is very similar to the code you have above. The only difference is that I dispensed with the use of `Promise.promisifyAll` - if you're writing the code yourself & you want to use promises, then do it yourself.

One important note: it's a good idea to include a `catch` handler. If you don't, your error will be swallowed up and disappear, and you'll be left wondering why your code is not working. Even if you don't think you'll need it, just write a catch handler that dumps it to `console.log`. You'll be glad you did!

Comment: I had initially done the same thing before I read this http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/279003. So I ended up using this approach. I also want to understand when do the require statements on top of each module run? The last part of my question.

Comment: Can you please get back to me on this? I am stuck on this issue.

Comment: It's my understanding (based solely on my own informal observation - I've never tested it) that the imports and requires are executed when a module is loaded. Regarding the link you posted in your comment: I hadn't seen that discussion - it suggests that performance is better using that approach. That may be true, and if performance is your primary concern, then go for it. I usually write code with a couple of other concerns in mind: keep the code simple & easy to read, and avoid including packages unless I need to.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. While performance may not be the primary concern for the app I am working on right now considering I am just doing it to learn. But my goal was to understand the correct and the best way of doing it. Any other improvements/suggestions on coding in nodejs/expressjs? This is my first app I am trying to write using node and mongo.